# Making a button larger, but keeping the text the same size

Tags: html, css

The button in html works perfectly. But I cannot get it styled correctly using CSS.

The goal is to get the button to look like this: 
[image]

When I add a width or padding/margin to the button it ruins the button style. It should also be responsive. Also for some reason I cannot change the color/border radius.
Tried doing it with an anchor tag as well to make a nice button, but that worked even less than this button.

I also run bootstrap seperately as CSS.

Snippet:

```css
#background-log {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.button-login {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #6441a4;
}

.twitch {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-log">
  <div class="button-login">
    <button class="twitch">Sign in with Twitch</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the above image buttons are using only css you shared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set `display:block;` for the button to make it a block-level element that you can properly apply width and padding/margin on. Use `width` on the button to make it wider, use `padding` to increase the space between text and button border and overwrite the default button values like `border` and `background` with the values you wish.

To make the buttons responsive, you can also use a percentage value for the width. You can also add a `border-radius` and `box-shadow` to make it look more like in your image. See the example below.

```css
#background-log {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.button-login {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
.button-login button {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.twitch {
  background-color: #6441a4;
}
.hitbox {
  background-color: #98cb01;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-log">
  <div class="button-login">
    <button class="twitch">Sign in with Twitch</button>
    <button class="hitbox">Sign in with Hitbox</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use bootstrap and set the button to

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
```

the class btn-block will make it full width with out missing up your padding.

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_button_block&stacked=h

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about making the button a bit larger then like you can see on the image. since it is kinda small atm (https://gyazo.com/f319a97bbb810626c9a8654d34d093b2) Adding a width to the id called background-log doesn't work and I don't know another way. If I add a width to the background, the button gets larger, but when I zoom in the text goes out of the button borders.

Comment: Really? suggesting an entire library for a simple button rule?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a violet button, add a `background-color` property to the button, not to the surrounding `div`. I reduced your example to clarify and also added a rounded border as in the example picture:

```
.twitch {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #6441a4;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 0px;
}
<button class="twitch">Sign in with Twitch</button>
```